Is there any way to disable the focus ring around the ShadCN dropdown menu?
I'm trying to configure the ModeToggle button that is in the ShadCN docs for light/dark mode theming and I'm bothered by the focus ring that appears next to the dropdown menu.
I looked into the code for the dropdown menu and tried to disable things such as bg:accent or bg:text-accent, etc. But I didn't get any change. Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Did you try my-element:focus { outline: none; } ?

Please never disable the focus rings. Instead customise them to match your theme
